# Palindrome language and Finite Automata Machines

Tags: automata-theory, probabilistic-automata

I'm a grad student in math. I'm unaware of available literature in theoretical computer science, so require suggestions for books. Here are the two topics I'm interested in exploring.

1) A complete treatment of palindrome language with reference to finite automata, particularly interested in how a probabilistic finite automate would recognize palindrome language.

2) A thorough treatment of context-sensitive languages. Introductory books don't discuss it in details as it is perhaps not a topic to be studied in a first course.

it appears that introductory books have rather sketchy discussions of the topics, mostly end of chapter problems. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding probabilistic (and quantum) automata, you may start by digging this survey: https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01988

For very recent results on quantum automata, you may check two recent works by Zachary Remscrim: https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/author/659/

Palindrome is an (exclusive) stochastic language, but a probabilistic machine requires log-space to recognize it with bounded error. Two-way quantum automata recognizes palindrome language with bounded-error in super-polynomial time.